Creating Drinking Glass using Solid of Revolution
I have to come up with two non-linear functions ($f(x)$ and $g(x)$) that will create a drinking glass when rotated 360 degrees around the y-axis.
The volume of the material of the drinking glass needs to be between $135$ $cm^3$ and $165$ $cm^3$.
The maximum capacity of the drinking glass needs to be between $225$ $mL$ and $275$ $mL$.
I'm trying to create a drinking glass that is easy to use, and I don't want my two functions to be too difficult to integrate so I've decided to use a cubic function for the outer layer and a parabola for the inner layer.
The problem is, I'm struggling to come up with the exact functions and limits/boundaries that will satisfy the material volume and maximum capacity requirements established above.
I've tried using ChatGPT to get started, but it's too prone to making errors to be useful.
Any assistance in approaching this problem would be much appreciated.

What two functions can I use for this problem?

A drinking glass that is easy to use is one that will stay upright on a table. I doubt that your choosen functions will ensure this. So why not start with a becher (mug, tumbler, goblet) to get the specified volumes (BTW, by $mL$ you mean $ml$ I suppose), then adjust some design details.

Stability is less of a concern with the right choice of cubic. A cup with an indented bottom is less likely to wobble (example cross section)

For an example design, consider a quadratic polynomial $p_2(x)$ and a cubic $p_3(x)$ such that

for simplicity, $p_2$ is free of both constant and linear terms, and $p_3$ is free of constant and quadratic terms. Thus $p_2(x)=ax^2$ and $p_3(x)=bx+cx^3=cx\left(x^2-\alpha^2\right)$ (denote the positive root of $p_3$ by $\alpha$);
for some $\beta>\alpha$, $p_2(\beta) = p_3(\beta) = B$, i.e. the curves meet at the brim of the cup;
$p_3$ is convex around a minimum $m$ attained for some $\gamma\in(0,\alpha)$. It's easy to show this is ensured when $b<0$ and $c>0$; and
the two volume constraints are met: $135 \le V_{\rm M} \le 165$ and $225 \le V_{\rm C} \le 275$, where $V_{\rm M}$ and $V_{\rm C}$ denote the volumes of the cup's material and contents, respectively. (Note that $1\,\mathrm{cm}^3$ is the same as $1\,\rm mL$.)

The idea is to end up with a stable cup possessing a cross section like below (disregarding how the pictured $p_2$ does not pass through the origin; not to scale):

Fix the two volumes. Via shell integration, it's easy to show that $V_{\rm C}$ depends on $(a,\beta,B)$ and $V_{\rm M}$ depends on $(a,b,c,\beta)$:
$$V_{\rm C} = 2\pi \int_0^\beta x \left(B - p_2(x)\right) \, dx \\
V_{\rm M} = 2\pi \int_0^\beta x \left(p_2(x) - p_3(x)\right) \, dx$$
From the first three conditions, we can set up and solve a linear system for $(a,b,c)$, once we choose reasonable starting values of $(\beta,\gamma,B)$ for a functional container:
$$\begin{cases} p_2(\beta) = B &\implies a = \dfrac B{\beta^2} \\[1ex] p_3(\beta) = B &\implies b+c\beta^2 = \dfrac B\beta \\[1ex] p_3'(\gamma) = 0 \land p_3''(\gamma) > 0 &\implies \gamma=\sqrt{-\dfrac bc}\end{cases}$$
Lastly, if you plan on actually manufacturing such a cup, you'll have to insert a constant term to either polynomial to adjust for the non-zero thickness at the base of the interior.
